# Filter Liferay HttpRequest

Tags: servlets, filter, attributes, liferay

I would like to filter (modify) HttpRequest, which is coming to target Liferay Servlet, intercept it and add some **attributes.** (for example User) and then redirect (forward) the request to the target servlet. I create new servlet that should work like interceptor, add the attribute (request.setAttribute("user", User)) and then either dispatcher.forward or response.redirect... This is only for testing purposes to be able to call some liferay functionality from tests.
The problem is that Liferay is filtering the request and add there its 7 attributes. I tried also create SimpleFilter, but its not called when target servlet is called, only when I create my own Servlet which extends HttpServlet. 
So the question is, is it possible to tell liferay not to filter the requests or more important not to remove the attributes from the request? I have debugged the Liferay source code, catch the Filter Chain and on the 1. filter I see there original request, and at the end the requests contains those Liferay attributes.

Many thanks.

The target servlet is defined like this:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>targetServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalDelegateServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>servlet-class</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.HttpRequestHandlerServlet</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>sub-context</param-name>
        <param-value>targetServlet</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Comment: ...and the version you're targeting is? Also: Could you elaborate on your underlying usecase/requirements? It feels like there's a simpler solution to it. It raises an eyebrow that you're trying to do some user handling yourself and implement a servlet on Liferay - typically that's not something you'd do in the portal environment.

Comment: Hi Olaf, thanks for your response. The usecase is simple, write integration test in Spring to be able to test the existing funkcionality in Liferay. SO there is a servlet, which is doing some business logic and at the end displays some JSON or string. But inside that logic, there is a call to authentificate user and at that point I failed. In real application of course user is logged in, but in the test scope (SpringJUnitRunner) there is no Liferay context or user. So I tried to modified the request  comming from Unit test before it hits the servlet and passed there an User object.

Comment: In that case, I'm leaning towards decoupling the business code from servlet interfaces, and test the extracted code. If you say "integration test", I'm assuming that you're running within an environment where Liferay is available. For Unit-Tests: Definitely extract and do *not* test *that* underlying Liferay functionality does what it should.

Comment: I understand what you mean Olaf, I can test the business logic by mocking the Liferay dependencies, thats how I did it at the end. I was looking more for a way of either intercepting the requests or initial the Liferay elements from Spring context. So instead of manually testing the functionality by login into the system and clicking through some pages, I could actually call the underlying logic (servlets or controllers) and simulate all of the user behavior.